# Random Sum of random variables: Without replacement

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

I have the numbers between 1 and 100 in an urn. I randomly draw $h$ many ($h$ fixed parameter) of them, without replacement. My random variable of interest is their sum.

All approaches I could think of are iterative logic ("If drawn this, then draw that second time,...") and become unmanageable when $h$ is large. Is there a generic way to compute the pdf of this RV?

I'm not familiar with characteristic functions, so I'd appreciate an approach more if it wouldn't require those.

Comment: May be easier to view it in the opposite direction, so look at the total sum of the balls in the urn, the remove balls and view the effect on the sum remaining.

Comment: @Andy Do I understand correctly that that approach works of $h$ sufficiently close to 100? In other words, if $h = 50$, it wouldn't matter from where I'd start, right?

Comment: One needs to find all ways to sum h numbers. The probability of every outcome is exactly the same as sampling doesnt change, i.e. sample 100 then 99 is the same as 99 then 100

Comment: so, when you draw $h$ balls you can obtain any sum in the range of $\tfrac{h(h+1)}{2}$ to $101h-\tfrac{h(h+1)}{2}$

Comment: Empirically for $h$ not close to $0$ or $100$, the distribution of the sum without replacement seems to be moderately well approximated by a normally distributed random variable with mean $\frac{101}{2}h$ and variance about $8.45 h(100-h)$, rounded to the nearest integer (and possibly with impossible values excluded)

Answer (score 5):

Not an answer but on simulation with $h = 50$, the pmf plot is,

[image: h=50]

Note that the sample space is integer values not real values.

**Edit 1:**

I am not sure whether a closed form solution for the pmf can be obtained. But here is an approach I tried. Since the order of samples doesn't matter when the sum is taken, therefore,

$$x_1 + x_2 + \ldots, x_h = x_{(1)} + x_{(2)} + \ldots, x_{(h)}$$

where $x_{(i)}$ is the $i$th order statistic.

Let us fix the sum to be $S$. We need to find the number of possible combinations $x{(i)}$'s such that,

$$x_{(1)} + x_{(2)} + \ldots, x_{(h)} = S$$

subject to

$$1 \leq x_{(1)} < x_{(2)} < \ldots < x_{(h)}$$

Introduce $a_1, a_2, \ldots a_{h-1}$ such that $a_i \geq 1$ and $\forall i\neq 1$,  $x_{(i)} = x_{(1)} + a_{1} + a_{2} + \ldots + a_{i-1}$. Then,

$$x_{(1)} + (x_{(1)} + a_{1}) + (x_{(1)} + a_{1} + a_{2}) + \ldots, (x_{(1)} + a_{1} + a_{2} + \ldots + a_{h-1}) = S$$

$$\implies hx_{(1)} + (h-1)a_{1} + \ldots + 2a_{h-2} + a_{h-1} = S$$

Take $y_1 = x_{(1)}-1$ and $\forall i\geq 2, y_i = a_{i-1}-1$. Then, our problem reduces to finding the combinations of $y_i$'s, such that,

$$hy_{1} + (h-1)y_{2} + \ldots + 2y_{h-1} + y_{h} = S - \frac{h(h+1)}{2}$$

subject to $y_i \geq 0$. The number of combinations will be equal to the coefficient of $z^{S - \frac{h(h+1)}{2}}$ in

$$(1-z^{h})^{-1}(1-z^{h-1})^{-1}\ldots(1-z)^{-1}$$

Now, I am not sure how to proceed further i.e. whether a closed form solution of the above coefficient can be obtained. If the value of coefficient is $C_S$, then $P(x_1+x_2+\ldots+x_h=S) = \frac{C_S}{\binom{100}{h}}$.

**Edit 2:**

$C_S$ can be calculated computationally using the recurrence given in this [wiki link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)#Restricted_part_size_or_number_of_parts) but there is no general formula to compute it.

Comment: Thanks for doing that. I guess it's naive of me but I expected the peak to be closer to $50 \times 50 =2500$?

Comment: No, the maximum will obtained at the value in the middle of $\frac{h(1+h)}{2}$ and $101h - \frac{h(1+h)}{2}$, which for $h=50$, will be $2525$.

Comment: My empirical suggestion (see comments to original question) might suggest a peak of your frequency distribution with $h=50$ of about $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\times8.45\times 50^2}} \approx 0.0027$, which seems credible

Answer (score 1):

This is a partial answer representing maybe the most naive approach (no tricks).

Call $X_1,\dots, X_h$ your draws and $S_h = X_1 + \dots + X_h.$ Now 
\begin{align}
p(S_h=n) &= h!\sum_{x_1,\dots x_h} \mathbf{1}(1\leq x_1 < \dots < x_h \leq 100)\mathbf{1}( \textstyle\sum x_i =n)p(x_1,\dots,x_h) \\
&=h!\frac{(100-h)!}{100!} \sum_{x_1,\dots x_h} \mathbf{1}(1\leq x_1 < \dots < x_h \leq 100)\mathbf{1}( \textstyle\sum x_i =n) \\
&= {100 \choose h}^{-1}\left(\text{partitions of }n\text{ with }h\text{ unique parts of size at most 100}\right).
\end{align}

For $n\leq 100 + (\textstyle\sum_{k=1}^{h-1}k)=100+\frac{h\cdot(h-1)}{2}$, the summation term can be computed through a recurrence relation defined here: [$p_k(n)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29#Restricted_part_size_or_number_of_parts).

(note that the support is $[\sum_{k=1}^hk,\sum_{k=100-h+1}^{100}k]=[h\cdot(h+1)/2, 100k +(h - h^2)/2]$ so this is not much at all.)

Comment: Not sure I understand your last sentence. $q(n)$ will give me the number of integer combinations that sum up to $n$. I don't see how I would impose the $h$ and $\leq 100$ restrictions there.

Comment: Yep, PartitionsQ was the wrong function. $${}$$ $100+h(h-1)/2$ is the largest number where all its $h$-unique-parts-partitions are 100 or less.  "$x_k=k$ for $k<h$ and $x_h=100$" is a valid partition for that number. Now think about what happens if you try and make any of the numbers in that partition greater than 100, or if you had chosen a larger integer to partition.